flutter firestore 'like' button is behaving strangely
I used Firebase queries so that when someone clicks the like button, it goes to the 'sendHearts' field, and conversely, when someone receives a like, it goes to the 'receivedHearts' field. However, as soon as I click the like button, it goes to the wrong place.
//receivedLike

Widget _receivedHearts(BuildContext context) {
    final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: db
            .collection(AppKeys.users)
            .where('receivedHearts', arrayContains: uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // print(snapshot);
          print(uid);
          print('snapshot : ${snapshot.data}');
          List<UsersModel> user = [];
          for (var docSnapshot in snapshot.data?.docs ?? []) {
            print('snapshot : ${snapshot.data?.docs}');
            user.add(UsersModel.fromDocument(docSnapshot));
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          }
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            default:
              return Container(

// sendLike

 Widget _sendHeart(BuildContext context) {
    final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: db
            .collection(AppKeys.users)
            .where('sentHearts', arrayContains: uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          List<UsersModel> user = [];
          for (var docSnapshot in snapshot.data?.docs ?? []) {
            user.add(UsersModel.fromDocument(docSnapshot));
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          }
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            default:
              return Container(

It seems like there's no problem, even though I've checked it multiple times. And I've also checked the database, but it seems like everything is going in correctly.
  Future<void> likePost(
      BuildContext context, UsersModel item, bool isLike) async {
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(AppKeys.users)
          .doc(item.id)
          .update(
        {
          'receivedHearts': FieldValue.arrayUnion([uid])
          // print(doc['sentHearts']);
        },
      );
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(AppKeys.users)
          .doc(uid)
          .update(
        {
          'sentHearts': FieldValue.arrayUnion([item.id]),
        },
      );

      print('sent 값 : ${item.sentHearts}');
      print('receive 값 : ${item.receivedHearts}');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> dislikePost(
      BuildContext context, UsersModel item, bool isLike) async {
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(AppKeys.users)
          .doc(item.id)
          .update(
        {
          'receivedHearts': FieldValue.arrayRemove([uid])
        },
      );
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(AppKeys.users)
          .doc(uid)
          .update(
        {
          'sentHearts': FieldValue.arrayRemove([item.id]),
        },
      );
      // print('receive 값 : ${item.receivedHearts}');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

And this is the button logic.
GestureDetector(

    onTap: () async {
      // bool isLike = item.sentHearts?.contains(uid) ?? false;

      bool newLikeState = !isLike;
      if (newLikeState) {
        print(
            'newlike : $newLikeState');
        try {
          await likePost(context,
              item, isLike);
          print(' : $isLike');
          setState(() {
            isLike = newLikeState;
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print('faild: $e');
        }
      } else {
        try {
          await dislikePost(context,
              item, isLike);
          print(
              'dislike : $isLike');
          setState(() {
            isLike = !newLikeState;
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print('failed: $e');
        }
      }
      print('final like : $isLike');
    },
    child: isLike
        ? SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/icons/smallHeart_on.svg')
        : SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/icons/smallHeart.svg'),
  )


The button is behaving strangely. The "like" is definitely being stored accurately in the database. I really don't know what's wrong.


Does it only occur if the field is not present in document. If so you can use set method with merge equals true. So that if field does not exist in document, it will create one. If this is not the case. Do you mind adding a video of what is the prblm. What does actually goes wrong.

@Ultranmus
Got it. Actually, I didn't upload the gif because I'm not used to using a MacBook. That would be more accurate.

From what I can see on the screen, it seems like when I click, it should go to the "sent to heart" section correctly, but it goes in the wrong direction. Also, when I add or remove from the database, it seems like it gets created only when someone sends it to me from among the fields of other people.
